# How to align origin's z axis to individual object's normals?

Tags: objects, normals, origin

I have an ico sphere and I need this random transform for the individual faces. I may solve this by using particles (but don't now how either) anyway...

[image: random transformation for objects]

when entering to edit mode and faces I have what I need, individual z axis oriented to normals but the randomize is hugely different and too much random for what I need...

What I want but not on edit mode but on object mode: [image]

What I get with randomize transform on edit mode: [image].

Now the big questions here are:

1. How do I orient origin's Z axis to individual normals in object mode?
2. Does blender have an addon for this?

thanks :)

Comment: Hello. You want to randomize each face depth along Z/normal keeping them aligned as they were before? That's it?

Comment: Yes, but as independent objects, and align each origin's Z to the normal of individual faces.